# how can the application determine when the fail-over has been triggered in azure cosmodb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

cosmodb can be configured to have the fail-over automatic from primary to secondary.

If my app needs to know when failover has happened, what can i use to determine that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by enabling [control plane diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/audit-control-plane-logs#control-plane-operations-for-azure-cosmos-account) for Region Failed Over then either use Azure Function with Alerts to notify your application